# Seeding a PRNG - Custom Setter

Tags: design-patterns, random, actionscript-3

I have a PRNG-Class called `Generator`. Now, after creating a new instance of it:

```
var g:Generator = new Generator();
```

**Custom function: `set_seed()`  -  Please review this approach.**

I call `g.set_seed();` which has the following logic:

```
public function set_seed(s:Number = 0):void
{
    seed = (s > 0) ? s : new Date().getTime();
}
```

- Pro: I can call it without any arguments, looks more beautiful in the classes I'm using it.
- Con: `set_seed` looks awful and I feel I should be using Flash's Getter/Setter approach.

(I'm getting the seed with: `get_seed();`)

Comment: What's the request here?  It doesn't appear that you're seeking a code review.

Comment: I want to get my Version with "set_seed()" reviewed.

Comment: Okay.  I'm not sure if there's much code here to review, but others can determine that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the generator to seed itself (using the current time) in its constructor.

Therefore, I would **not** use a default parameter in your `set_seed` method.

Also, in your current code, you treat all the negative values the same as zero. I wouldn't recommend that. Many random seeders can handle negative seeds as well, if you don't want to do that: *Throw an Exception/Error!*

Therefore, I would use this:

```
public function set_seed(s: Number): void
{
    if (s < 0) {
        throw new Error("Seed must be positive");
    }
    seed = s;
}
```

For comparison and inspiration, check Java's [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. Note that it has two constructors available, one for initializing to System's seed and one for initializing to a specific seed. That is an approach I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks alot for your fast answer; If I want to change the seed later, should I create a new Instance or would you suggest changing the value with Flash's Getter/Setter, my own or directly?

Comment: @gonida I only know limited things about what you are making. Do what you feels best. You can still have a `set_seed` method if you'd like (note that the Java class also has `setSeed`).